# How do I work with and open 360 degree *.pano panoramic image files?

Tags: photo-management, photo

Microsoft's Photosynth (uploaded via iOS app) website exports to *.pano. Facebook now supports 360 degree photos natively. How would I work with the metadata and/or view these 360 degree panoramic photos?

Comment: If this isn't strictly an Ubuntu issue, you may prefer to ask in superusers.com.

Comment: But I know how to do it on Windows and Mac. I only want to know how to do it on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open *.pano on Linux, build this:

https://github.com/photosynth/offlineViewer

To access metadata, extract the *.pano as a ZIP archive.

Comment: Please don't post just links.  Explain how the OP must go about doing it.

Comment: Are you suggesting copy-pasting the build instructions from the link?  However, the build instructions will be useless if the link does down, since there will be nothing to build.